# MySqlConnector - Parameter in dynamic string query won't be set

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

@pName is the parameter set in C# code by:

```cs
using (MySqlCommand dynamicQueryCommand = new MySqlCommand(dynamicQueryWithParameter, conn))
{
    dynamicQueryCommand.Parameters.Add("@pName", MySqlDbType.String);
    dynamicQueryCommand.Parameters["@pName"].Value = "John";

    using (MySqlDataReader dynamicQueryReader = dynamicQueryCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        string output = "";
        object[] values = new object[dynamicQueryReader.FieldCount];

        while (dynamicQueryReader.Read())
        {
            dynamicQueryReader.GetValues(values);

            output += values[0] + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the query in dynamicQueryWithParameter:

```mysql
SET @sql = 'select name from person';

SET @sql = Concat(@sql, ' WHERE name = @pName ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

@pName doesn't seem to be set.

The output is always that as if @pName would be null.

I would expect the query to look like:

```mysql
select name from person
where name = 'John'
```

I tried different format, like:

```mysql
SET @sql = Concat(@sql, ' WHERE name = '@pName' ');
```

or

```mysql
SET @sql = Concat(@sql, ' WHERE name = ''@pName'' ');
```

But this did not work.

Is that a bug in the MySqlConnector, a syntax error on my side or something different?

---

Update:

There are some workarounds, for example using the 'USING', like Marc Gravell suggested, but I think, when the query might be longer and needs to be altered at some point, counting the '?' in the query to add a new parameter might be prone to errors. I guess the order after the 'USING' matters.

The other workaround would be to create a temporary user-definded-variable and use that one in the string query:

```mysql
SET @pName_var = @pName;

SET @sql = 'select name from person';

SET @sql = Concat(@sql, ' WHERE name = @pName_var ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This works and gets the desired output, so it seems it really might be a bug or a non supported feature of the MySqlConnector?

Or did I make an error somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that there's no need to use `EXECUTE` here, you need `USING` to bind parameters, using `?` for the placeholder in the inner SQL:

```sql
SET @sql = 'select name from person where name = ?';
-- etc
EXECUTE stmt
    USING @pname
```

[Citation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html) and [examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

However, in this case your SQL should just be:

```sql
select name from person
where name = @pname
```

without the manual `EXECUTE`

---

IMO the real trick here is to move the decision-making into your application code, which is vastly more scalable; for example (here using Dapper):

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder("select name from person");
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
{
    sb.Append(" where name = @name");
}
var sql = sb.ToString();
foreach (var row in connection.Query<string>(sql, new { name }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(row);
}
```

Dapper is sensible enough not to actually add the `@name` parameter (that it sees via `new { name }`) unless it appears in the query (`sql`), which will only be the case if `name` has a non-trivial value.

Comment: Regarding conditional concatenation I found it easier to use those string-queries.
Thanks for suggesting the 'USING', but I think, when the query might be longer and needs to be altered at some point, counting the '?' in the query to add a new parameter might be prone to errors. I guess the order after the 'USING' matters.

It seems antother workaround might be using a temporary user-defined-variable, but maybe there are other ways?
I will update my question for that.

Comment: @mitdm have you considered building the conditional (and parameterized) SQL in C# code, and just executing a simple SQL query? your database engine is the *worst* place to build queries, honestly. If you execute it with things like Dapper, it can automate selecting which parameters to actually include

Comment: Yes, I have, but currently I would I need to reset a dictionary each time for that and refill it again, when I build that SQL-query in C#. I thought it would be more performant, when I put it into a dynamic sql query.
After some measureing for creating a new dictionary it seems, it is still very fast, so yes, I could just build the query in C# code.
I am still curious, why the parameter setting doesn't work, if the parameter is in a string. Like the very first example in  my question.

Comment: @mitdm that's a: not true (see edit for example), b: even if true, it would be irrelevant - that will be immeasurable compared to the database access, and again: you want your database to do the *least possible work* - it is your bottleneck

Comment: What exactly is not true? By "Yes, I have" I meant I considered to build the query in C# code.
Also thanks for pointing out that the database is considered a bottleneck, I didn't know that.

Comment: @mitdm "but currently I would I need to reset a dictionary each time for that and refill it again" - see edit, no dictionaries

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification.

What I meant with that is, with my current implementation I would need to reset a Dictionary, not the one simplified and displayed here as the example for my question.
I am sorry for causing some confusion.

Comment: For database-independence I currently (want to) store all direct SQL-queries in a dictionary, which is (normally) created only once at runtime, and when I create the query at client side (in e.g. C# code) the dictionary would need to be reset and then created again. I feared that the recreation might impact performance, hence my approach to get the if working in SQL, but it seems to build a new dictionary is very fast. So I will rather buld the queries with concatenational/conditional logic on the client side now.